# how to detect when UITextField is the first Responder

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to detect when user select a text field ? i want to delete the UItextField.Text When user slect the UItextField . for exemple i have userName Field with a default text " enter your user name " . And i want to delete the text when the UITextField become the first responder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add your textField a change property like that:

```
[nameText addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Then create your textFieldDidChange method here:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDidChange:(id)sender
{
NSString* nm = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString* ys = [[NSString alloc] init];

if(sender == nameText)
{

    nameText.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [nameLabel setText:nm];

}
else
{
    yasText.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [yasLabel setText:ys];
}
}
```

This is the sample code you can change it in your purpose.

Comment: This is NOT the correct answer. What you should do is use the placeholder property as some of the other answers here do.

Answer (score 8):

Try using the UITextField placeholder property instead.

For example:

```
UITextField *userName= [[UITextField alloc] 
                 initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
userName.placeholder = @"enter your user name";
```

That's it. You're done. Apple will handle the rest for you, so its really a much better way than trying to do it all yourself.

Comment: @albertamg @Richard tahnk you very much but i surched in sof and i don't understand how to use palceholder ... Can you help me please ? i'am new in iphone dev

Comment: I added example code for you. I think this is a better way than doing what you are trying. Try it out and you'll see.

Answer (score 2):

Use the placeholder property of `UITextField` as suggested by `@Richard Brightwell.`

You could use it as below

```
myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
.............................................................................
.............................................................................
myTextField.placeholder = @"Enter your user name " ;
.............................................................................
```

For more check the Apple Documentation for [UITextField](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) .

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but I wanted to added swift 3.0 version. You can set the viewcontroller as a delegate of UITextfield in viewDidLoad method then implement delegate method. Swift 3.0

```
class myViewController: UIViewController {

  //other properties
  @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    myTextField.delegate = self
    ....
  }
...
}

extension myViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.text = ""
    ...
  }
```